# RestTemplate received response not in json

Tags: java, spring, groovy, jwt, spock

While writing integration test in spock for my rest api secured with JWT i faced problem with response content type. For swagger or postman there's no problem. It's only happens with integration test.

Log from test start:

```
18:24:57.101 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP POST http://localhost:8080/login
18:24:57.110 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
18:24:57.138 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{login=test, password=test}] as "application/json"
18:24:57.282 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 200 OK
18:24:57.284 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1"
```

Here is response from server

```
<200,###BODY###,[Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Authorization:###JWT_TOKEN###, X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Content-Type:"application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Date:"Sun, 31 Jan 2021 16:58:29 GMT", Keep-Alive:"timeout=60", Connection:"keep-alive"]>
```

as result i obviously received:

> Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

Here is my test:

```
def 'should login player' (){
    given:
    def credentials = [
            "login"   : "test",
            "password": "test"
    ]

    when:
    def response = sendPost(credentials, "login", String.class)
    def body = parseResponse(response)
    then:
    (body.Authentication as String).contains("Bearer")
}
def rest = new RestTemplate()
def headers = new HttpHeaders()
def url = "http://localhost:8080/"


def setup() {
    rest.messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter())
    rest.messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter())
    headers.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
    headers.remove("Accept")
    headers.add("Accept", APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
}


def sendPost(def body, String endpoint, Class returnType) {
    def httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers)
    rest.postForEntity((url + endpoint), httpEntity, returnType)
}
```

Can't understand why in log i can see Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, /]

if i set only application/json.
Even setting contentType to json in successfulyAuthentication method doesn't help.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: _Disclaimer: I am not a Spring user._ Are you sure that the `HttpEntity` constructor knows what to do with `credentials` as its body parameter, given the fact that its type is `Map` (during runtime probably a `LinkedHashMap` in Groovy)? Maybe you think it is JSON because map literals look so similar in Groovy. but in fact it is not. Maybe you need something like `new JsonBuilder(credentials).toString()` or optionally the fancier `new JsonBuilder(credentials).toPrettyString()`. Let me know if this helps, then I can convert the comment into an answer.

Comment: I can see on spring side that request was handled correctly, You can also see that in response i have Authorization which confirm that data provided in request was correct. No idea why response is in such wierd format.

Comment: Well, I cannot see much in those logs. BTW, I just reformatted them to be more readable. You also did not tell me where the exception occurred (stack trace). You also seem to have censored the `###BODY###` and I cannot see the definition of the `parseResponse` method. Maybe you want to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and then edit your question in order to be one. Feel free to also share a sample GitHub repository. If the people here can reproduce your problem, you dramatically increase the probability of getting spot-on answers.

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback in order to close this question which is still listed as unanswered. Thank you. I would subsequently delete this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delay.

Yeah the problem was argument of parseResponse. I've been working on whole response instead of only body.

It should looks like `def body = parseResponse(response.body)`

Thanks for your time investigating it!!